# How to put input matrix in function in R (rmoo nsga2)

Tags: r, function, matrix, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to solve a multi-objective problem using nsga2 function in rmoo package of R

However, some errors keep occurring in my code.

"Error in tourLength(x, ...) : argument "data" is missing, with no default"

Briefly, I want to put a fixed metrix (data) as an input to a function.

I want to find the optimal solution such as the decision x values using the input matrix (data).

Below is a simple example.

#### simple code

```
library(data.table)
library(rmoo)

data<-c(0,1,3,5,7)
data<-matrix(data, ncol=5, nrow=5, byrow = TRUE) # this is input matrix

tourLength <- function(x,data) {
  x <- matrix(x, nrow = 1)
  data1<-data*x[1]+data*x[2]
  sum(data1[,3])
}
tspFitness <- function(x, ...) 1/tourLength(x, ...)

result <- nsga2(type = "real-valued", data = data,
                fitness = tspFitness,
                lower = c(0.01,0.01),
                upper = c(1,1),
                popSize = 100,
                monitor = FALSE,
                maxiter = 10)
```

I would really appreciate your help!!

Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

`nObj` parameter has strange default value. Just put `nObj = 2`.

**note**:

I've have no idea what your fitness function is calculating (it seems like something copied from `GA` package for TSP and modified)